# API Errors: #/paths: Additional properties not allowed:

Tags: swagger

I have a service on node.js, which is run locally and when I build it via docker (which is the way we deploy). But on kubernetes environment after deploy this service I am getting the following error:

```
    API Errors:

      #/paths: Additional properties not allowed: 

    1 error and 0 warnings
```

I have overlooked the whole possible answers here and in the google, but have not found any related to such empty "paths" (usually `#/paths` is more logical and after `allowed:` is written something).

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Ace question is that service is not run, because of this error. But I have found what's wrong, somehow there was an `undefined` route, which is actually result of silent error in the question.